# How to access WAMP database from remote computer using JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to access the database on a WAMP server on my friend's PC from my own PC using a java application. It works well when I connect to my localhost's database using JDBC, but how can I connect to my friend's PC in the same LAN?

Steps that I did before:

- In Appache -> httpd.conf , i make a change  " Allow from 10.0.0.131 "
- conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.131:3306/mydb","root","");

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a username in MySQL that has a more liberal "HOST" as well. Generally "Root" is set up with a Host of 127.0.0.1, and Localhost. Meaning it will only allow "Root" to connect if it is from the same computer. I believe you can % to allow all hosts to connect with that user. Obviously throwing a wild card in there presents potential security issues, but it's great for debugging.

Edited to add: You don't need to monkey around with Apache permissions. This is purely a MySQL permission issue.

Comment: I will try if it only needs a username and making the host %.